# How do I save the entire graph without it being cut off?

Tags: python, matplotlib, png, data-visualization, pie-chart

I'm trying to graph a pie chart using myplotlib, and I was able to set the spacing and the end result with `plt.show()` is exactly what I want. However whenever I try to save my figure using `plt.savefig("file path name here.png")` The title and portions of the labels are cut off.

I have tried using `plt.tight_layout()` however, that completely removes all the spacing I set up beforehand. I also tried `plt.savefig("file path name.png", dpi=...)` however that just increases the size of the saved png creating a bigger image that has its title and labels cut off.

```
Dict_July=dict(Apps["July"].value_counts())
Dict_Aug=dict(Apps["August"].value_counts())
Dict_Sept=dict(Apps["September"].value_counts())
Dict_Oct=dict(Apps["October"].value_counts())
Dict_Nov=dict(Apps["November"].value_counts())
Dict_Jan=dict(Apps["January"].value_counts())
Dict_Feb=dict(Apps["Feb/Mar"].value_counts())
Dict_April=dict(Apps["April"].value_counts())

App_Errors=[Dict_July, Dict_Aug, Dict_Sept, Dict_Oct, Dict_Nov, Dict_Jan, Dict_Feb, Dict_April]

App_Names=["None","2020","CRM","Other","3C Logic","Outlook","Act-on","Foxit"]
colors=["c","orangered","lime","gold","mediumorchid","mediumslateblue","fuchsia","mediumspringgreen"]
july_leg_values=[]
july_legend=[]

for x in range(len(App_Names)):
    try:
        july_leg_values.append(App_Errors[0][App_Names[x]])
        july_legend.append(App_Names[x])
    except:
        "test"

plt.pie(july_leg_values, labels=july_legend,shadow=True,colors=colors, autopct="%1.1f%%", radius=1.6, explode=(.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
plt.title("July 2017 App Errors",y=1.3,fontsize=14, fontweight="bold")

plt.savefig("./Images/July_App.png")
```

Examples of what I created vs what is saved as are [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W5TE.jpg).

Comment: radius=1.6 creates a pie that is larger than the figure, so it gets cut off. Use radius =1 or similar to have the complete pie within the figure.

Comment: So is there no way to save the picture as is? I set it to radius 1.6 for more visibility, which is why I was avoiding using plt.tight_layout() because it set radius to 1.

Comment: If you want to have a larger figure use `plt.figure(figsize=(8,7))` or whatever numbers you need.

Answer (score 2):

use **bbox_inches='tight'**

plt.savefig('file_name.png', bbox_inches='tight')